# postgres use of rank function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, rank

Am new to Sql queries. I need to build a query which will rank the student based on number of test on which he has got 100% divide by total number of test he has taken and consider only test which are 10 days old. Here is my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE student(
id serial NOT NULL,student_email varchar NULL,
student_name varchar NULL,
test_subject varchar NULL,
total_question varchar NULL,
total_passed varchar NULL,
total_failed varchar NULL,
total_skipped varchar NULL,
test_time timestamp NULL,
CONSTRAINT student PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

if a student has total_failed or total_skipped not 0 then that test is not considered has 100%.

sample data will be like

```
1   j@b.com john    maths   10  10  0   0   2019-08-20 21:00:00
2   j@b.com john    maths   10  10  0   0   2019-08-19 21:00:00
3   j@b.com john    maths   10  09  1   0   2019-08-18 21:00:00
4   j@b.com john    english 10  10  0   0   2019-08-20 21:00:00
5   j@b.com john    english 10  10  0   0   2019-08-19 21:00:00
6   j@b.com john    english 10  09  0   1   2019-08-20 21:00:00
7   p@b.com paul    maths   10  10  0   0   2019-08-20 21:00:00
8   p@b.com paul    maths   10  10  0   0   2019-08-19 21:00:00
9   p@b.com paul    maths   10  10  0   0   2019-08-18 21:00:00
10  k@b.com koki    maths   10  10  0   0   2019-06-20 21:00:00
11  k@b.com koki    english 10  10  0   0   2019-06-20 21:00:00
12  k@b.com koki    science 10  10  0   0   2019-08-20 21:00:00
13  k@b.com koki    maths   10  08  2   0   2019-08-20 21:00:00
14  k@b.com koki    english 10  10  0   0   2019-08-20 21:00:00
```

from the above data set i need to consider only those data which are with in 10 days and give the "RANK" based on total number of test with 100% divided by total number of test for every distinct subject_name,student.
output of above dataset will be

```
koki    science 100%   k@b.com
koki    english 100%   k@b.com
paul    maths   100%   p@b.com
john    maths   66.6%  j@b.com
john    english 66.6%  j@b.com
koki    science 0%     k@b.com
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I

- translate your definition of `rank`:

  > total number of test with 100% divided by total number of test

  as

  ```
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE total_passed = total_question) / COUNT(*)::real
  ```
- and apply the filter for the last 10 days:

  ```
  test_time > CURRENT_DATE - interval '10 days'
  ```

I end up with the following query

```
SELECT  
  student_name
, test_subject
, COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE total_passed = total_question) / COUNT(*)::real student_rank

FROM student 
WHERE test_time > CURRENT_DATE - interval '10 days' 
GROUP BY 1, 2 
ORDER BY 3 desc;
```

I get the desired output:

```
 student_name | test_subject |   student_rank
--------------+--------------+-------------------
 paul         | maths        |                 1
 koki         | english      |                 1
 koki         | science      |                 1
 john         | maths        | 0.666666666666667
 john         | english      | 0.666666666666667
 koki         | maths        |                 0
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation.  In this case, `avg()` should work:

```
select student_name, test_subject,
       avg( (total_failed + total_skipped = 0)::int ) as ratio_passed
from t
where test_time > now() - interval 10 day
group by student_name, test_subject;
```

Comment: am getting couple of error running this SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "10"
  Position: 161
  ERROR: syntax error at or near "10"
  Position: 161
  ERROR: syntax error at or near "10"
  Position: 161

Comment: if i remove 10 days filter  SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying + character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 54
  ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying + character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts
  ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying + character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: total_failed and total_skipped are varchar